# Dispose of a pictureBox image without losing the pictureBox

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory, picturebox, dispose

I am writing a program that will play a slideshow (among other things). The slideshow is controlled by a backgroundWorker, and is set to a while(true) loop so it will constantly play images. My problem is I'm not sure how to dispose of the old images so they don't take up memory (after a while the program throws an "Out of memory exception). If I call horPicBox.Image.Dispose() then it won't let me use the pictureBox at all after that.

Is there a way to release the old image from memory?? If I look at the diagnostic tools in VS, the memory goes up each time the image changes ...
[image]

Note: ImagePaths is a List of the filepaths for the slideshow images.

This is the code the backgroundWorker runs:

```
private void PlayImages()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int index;
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

        while (true)
        {
            index = r.Next(imagePaths.Count);
            horPicBox.Image = Image.FromFile(imagePaths[index]);

            watch.Start();

            while (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 5000)
            {

            }

            watch.Stop();
            watch.Reset();

            //picWorker.ReportProgress(0);
        }
    }
```

I can report progressChanged to the UI thread, but I'm not sure what I need to do from the UI thread (if anything) to release the old Image(s). Thanks in advance!!

Comment: *If I call horPicBox.Image.Dispose() then it won't let me use the pictureBox at all after that* what, it sends a bouncer over who roughs you up if you try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the number of images and total size? I think it is better to load all images in array and assign them to `horPicBox` than loading them multiple times. To use `Dispose` first assign `horPicBox.Image` to temp object, then assign `horPicBox.Image` to `null` or next image and call `Dispose` at the end for the temp object:

```
Image img = horPicBox.Image;
horPicBox.Image = Image.FromFile(imagePaths[index]);
if ( img != null ) img.Dispose();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are hundreds of images, so if I pre-load them, it gives a memory exception

Answer (score 6):

What if you store the image to variable of that type and then set your picturebox image and then dispose the older one like

```
       Image oldImage = horPicBox.Image;
       horPicBox.Image = Image.FromFile(imagePaths[index]);
       oldImage.Dispose();
```

Comment: That works wonderfully! Thanks a lot! (Since i486 said it first, I'll give the answer to them)