# Issue with Picturebox not updating when rows or cells selected in a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am building a database of trading cards, the front end I have made in c# winforms for it displays the datagridview just fine, but when the cells for the various cards are selected (each card is one row) it is only loading the image for the first row and displaying only that image in a picturebox, and ignoring the others. I have attempted multiple methods to get the control to update with little success.

What I have tried - dgv1 is the datagridview, similar code was added to the mouse over event:

```
private void dgv_CellStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string setcode = (string)dgv1.Rows[e.Cell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value;
            string cardname = (string)dgv1.Rows[e.Cell.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value;
            string imgpath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "pics", setcode, cardname + ".full.jpg");

            pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();

            using (Image myImage = Image.FromFile(imgpath))
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = (Image)myImage.Clone();
                pictureBox1.Update();
            }

        }
```

this code doesn't seem to work either:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(imgpath); 
pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

I have also attempted other methods I've found while searching this site and have only been able to show 1 image, after which the control only ever shows that image and none of the others.

Added additional detail in the form of a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hODwk8wJZGU Note the image still doesn't change.

Comment: Under EXACTLY what circumstances do you want the image to change in the `PictureBox`? I would suggest that you're handling the wrong event, for one thing. You should probably be binding your data to a `BindingSource` and binding that to the grid, then handling the `CurrentChanged` event of the `BindingSource`. You would then get the data from the `Current` property of the `BindingSource` and just set the `ImageLocation` property of the `PictureBox`.

Comment: It could be the way you're calling dispose on the picturebox.image is causing it to fail after the first one. Try not calling dispose. [But if you must, try this method to toss it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39440021/3585500)

Comment: Are you sure the event is being called and no exceptions are being thrown?  Use your second case (not the first where you are disposing the image).  Put a breakpoint on `pictureBox.Refresh()` and make sure it's being hit.  Also, verify the value in `imgpath` is the image you are expecting.

Comment: Change the event you're handling to `RowEnter` -- Replace (and don't use anymore) `Environment.CurrentDirectory` with `Application.StartupPath` -- You can set `pictureBox1.ImageLocation = imgpath;` to specify the path of the Image (assuming the path you're building is correct)

Comment: @Patrick all breakpoints I have set are being hit

Comment: @Jimi that doesn't seem to work either, and I've checked the files exist etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your post states that you want to be able to update a PictureBox with an image of a trading card when rows or cells are selected in a DataGridView. Your latest comment indicates that other suggestions haven't helped so far. So, rather than trying to diagnose from your code sample what isn't working what I can offer is an example of what will.

Sometimes it's easier to test our coding assumptions by taking something that *works* and introducing incremental changes until it *breaks* so I would encourage you to [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/select-card-game-picture-from-dgv.git) my minimal sample and experiment with it.

Handling the `SelectionChanged` event is one way to achieve this outcome and since I don't have easy access a license for ***trading*** card images, I will demonstrate using an open source library for ***playing*** cards instead.

[image: screenshot]

**Image credit**: [Boardgame pack v2](https://opengameart.org/content/boardgame-pack) (Creative Commons License) by Kenney Vleugels.

---

**DataBinding**

The excellent comment by jmcilhinney suggests data binding. So how *exactly* would you do that? Basically, you make a class to represent a row of data, for example:

```
enum Value { Joker, Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Back }
enum Suit { Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades, }
class Card
{
    // Internal set makes the cell read only
    public Value Value { get; internal set; }
    public Suit Suit { get; internal set; }
}
```

Then you make a `BindingList<Card>` and assign it to the `DataSource` property of your DataGridView in the method that loads your main form class.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _imageBase = $"{GetType().Namespace}.Images.boardgamePack_v2.PNG.Cards";
        pictureBoxCard.Image = getCardImage(Value.Back);
    }
    private readonly string _imageBase;
    BindingList<Card> Cards = new BindingList<Card>();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        dataGridViewCards.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridViewCards.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridViewCards.DataSource = Cards;

        #region F O R M A T    C O L U M N S
        Cards.Add(new Card()); // <- Auto generate columns
        dataGridViewCards.Columns["Value"].AutoSizeMode= DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridViewCards.Columns["Suit"].AutoSizeMode= DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        Cards.Clear();
        #endregion F O R M A T    C O L U M N S

        // Add a few cards
        Cards.Add(new Card { Value = Value.Ten, Suit = Suit.Diamonds });
        Cards.Add(new Card { Value = Value.Jack, Suit = Suit.Clubs });
        Cards.Add(new Card { Value = Value.Queen, Suit = Suit.Hearts });
        Cards.Add(new Card { Value = Value.King, Suit = Suit.Spades });
        Cards.Add(new Card { Value = Value.Ace, Suit = Suit.Diamonds });

        // Subscribe to the event that occurs when selection changes.
        dataGridViewCards.ClearSelection();
        dataGridViewCards.SelectionChanged += onSelectionChanged;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

As shown above, the data binding lets you add and remove cards from the DGV by manipulating the data in the `Cards` collection instead of having to work with the UI control directly.

---

**Handle event**

```
    private void onSelectionChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridViewCards.CurrentCell == null)
        {
            pictureBoxCard.Image = getCardImage(Value.Back);
        }
        else
        {
            int row = dataGridViewCards.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            if((row != -1) && (row < Cards.Count)) 
            {
                Card card = Cards[row];
                pictureBoxCard.Image = getCardImage(card);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Load Images**

You will also need a reliable means to locate and load an image. One good way is to set the `Build Action` property of your images to `Embedded resource`.

[image: embed images]

Now the image can be retrieved based on the card's value and suit.

```
BindingList<Card> Cards = new BindingList<Card>();
private Image getCardImage(Value value = Value.Joker, Suit? suit = null)
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case Value.Ace:
            return localImageFromResourceName($"{_imageBase}.card{suit}A.png");
        case Value.Jack:
            return localImageFromResourceName($"{_imageBase}.card{suit}J.png");
        case Value.Queen:
            return localImageFromResourceName($"{_imageBase}.card{suit}Q.png");
        case Value.King:
            return localImageFromResourceName($"{_imageBase}.card{suit}K.png");
        case Value.Joker:
            return localImageFromResourceName($"{_imageBase}.cardJoker.png");
        case Value.Back:
            return localImageFromResourceName($"{_imageBase}.cardBack_green3.png");
        default:
            return localImageFromResourceName($"{_imageBase}.card{suit}{(int)value}.png");
    }
    Image localImageFromResourceName(string resource)
    {
        using (var stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource)!)
        {
            return new Bitmap(stream);
        }
    }
}
private Image getCardImage(Card card) => getCardImage(card.Value, card.Suit);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer -My concern with this though, is I am working with 45k cards over the history of a popular trading card franchise. I am not too familiar with binding sources, but it's probably a good time to brush up as it has been a while since I last touched c#. I can see the image path being changed in code, but is not being reflected in the picturebox.